# Running Multiple Instances of Flash Media Live Encoder on Mac

Tags: macos, flash, vlc, live-streaming, fmle

Is there a way to run multiple instances of Flash Media Live Encoder (FMLE) on a Mac? I have a live stream running from VLC to FMLE and would like to have 2 streams using the same computer.

I've managed to get 2 instances of VLC running on the same computer using the script from this link:

https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_play_multiple_instances_of_VLC/

```
on run
do shell script "open -n /Applications/VLC.app"
end run

on open theFiles
repeat with theFile in theFiles
    do shell script "open -na /Applications/VLC.app " & quote & (POSIX path of theFile) & quote
end repeat
end open
```

Is there a way i can do the same with FMLE?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this right by running the following command in terminal.

```
n=2 ; for (( c=1; c<=n; c++)) ; do open -n /Applications/Adobe/FlashMediaLiveEncoder32/FMLE.app/ ; done
```

I had to remove the spaces in the folder names and .app name as well so it would work in terminal.